# Using LINQ to select particular XML root

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following problem and I am working with this type of XML structure:

```
<directory>

     <ContactDirectory header="Foo1">
        <Person name="Person 1" number="Person 2">
      </ContactDirectory>

      <ContactDirectory name="Foo2">
        <Person name="Person 2" number="Person 2">
      </ContactDirectory>
</directory>
```

Now currently, I'm using a dictionary and storing the values as such:

```
var contacts = element.Descendants("Person").ToDictionary(datenum => datenum.Attribute("name").Value,
            datenum => datenum.Attribute("number").Value);
```

This works find and in the "element" is just going through the structure.

The problem is this: Whenever I do this, it just selects the first XML root tag and does not consider any others.

What I want to happen: Whenever a user selects which directory to choose, the XML for this particular header is shown and stored inside a dictionary.

I have tried: For my first attempt, I tried to use a LINQ statement which had a WHERE clause in it:

```
var selectedContacts = element.Descendants("Person").Where(element.Attribute("header").ToString() == "Foo1").Select(element.Attribute("name").Value);
```

However this does not work, and gives me a: `Does not contain a definition for 'Where'....

Where am I going wrong? P.S. I'm learning LINQ.

Comment: where is the header attribute ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use linq in this way:

```
var selectedContacts = element.Descendants("Person")
                          .Where(x=>x.Parent.Attribute("name").Value == "Foo1")
                          .Select(x=>x.Attribute("name").Value);
```

Convert to Dic:

```
var selectedContacts = element.Descendants("Person")
                          .Where(x=>x.Parent.Attribute("name").Value == "Foo1")
                          .ToDictionary(datenum => datenum.Attribute("name").Value,
                                        datenum => datenum.Attribute("number").Value);
```

Comment: Thank you but how would I be able to convert this to a dictionary?

Comment: This won't work since I think your code thinks that I'm trying to request "header" inside of the "Person" tag where it should be inside the "ContactDirectory"?

Comment: @user1326876 have you try my code? what i do is: trying to request "header" inside of the "ContactDirectory"  already!

Comment: Yeah, I just get a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` I don't get where you try to request "header" inside of ContactDirectory?

Answer (score 0):

First the correct xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<directory>
   <ContactDirectory name="Foo1">
      <Person name="Person 1" number="Person 2" />
   </ContactDirectory>
   <ContactDirectory name="Foo2">
      <Person name="Person 2" number="Person 2" />
   </ContactDirectory>
</directory>
```

<kbd>Edit</kbd> -> <kbd>Paste Special</kbd> -> <kbd>Paste as XML classes</kbd> + refactor:

```
public class Master
{
    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class directory
    {
        [XmlElement("ContactDirectory")]
        public directoryContactDirectory[] ContactDirectory { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class directoryContactDirectory
    {
        public directoryContactDirectoryPerson Person { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class directoryContactDirectoryPerson
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string number { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Code example:

```
        Master.directory directory;
        const string data = @"
            <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
            <directory>
               <ContactDirectory name='Foo1'>
                  <Person name='Person 1' number='Person 2' />
               </ContactDirectory>
               <ContactDirectory name='Foo2'>
                  <Person name='Person 2' number='Person 2' />
               </ContactDirectory>
            </directory>";
        if (data.Deserialize(out directory))
        {
            var contacts = directory.ContactDirectory.ToDictionary(
                o => o.name, 
                o => o.Person.number);
        }
```

Extension method :

```
    public static bool Deserialize<T>(this String str, out T item)
    {
        item = default(T);
        bool success;
        try
        {
            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(str)))
            {
                item = (T)ser.Deserialize(reader);
            }
            success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            success = false;
        }

        return success;
    }
```

Comment: It is better to Deserialize data first and then use Linq to query what you want.